# Android Transparent Activity doesn't cover the whole screen

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-manifest, android-styles

I have been attempting to create an Activity that is opaque which overlaps another activity that is being shown in the background.

This is my XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".EmergencyActivity">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@color/opaque_back">

        <Button
                android:text="Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file:

```
      <activity
            android:name=".EmergencyActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
```

Style:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Images of the screens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idzb4.jpg  - first activity screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/254F5.jpg  - screen of the activity that isn't being fully displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing from appCompactActivity to Activity in order to use another style which isn't supported by the AppCompactActivity.

I changed the manifest to:

```
<activity
        android:name=".EmergencyActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough but if you want to make an activity display full screen try this inside the activity class :

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: It didn't work. I have added the second screenshot that should make the problem more clear